# AngularJS: Dúvidas com template complexo

Tags: javascript, angularjs, layout

Preciso criar uma página em que o template deve variar de acordo com o solicitado. Por exemplo, na página inicial tenho um espaço para conteúdo em abas e uma coluna fixa (conforme imagem abaixo). Tanto as abas quanto a coluna são independentes.

Porém, para todas as demais páginas o template é diferente (não tem a barra lateral). Como devo proceder neste caso?

[image: Exemplo do template inicial]

Comment: Ola Danilo, eu sugiro voce dar uma olhada no UI-Router https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router que permite que voce tenha "nested views" (basicamente um template dentro do outro). Com o router padrao do AngularJS voce tem apenas um /ng-view. Com o ui-router eh possivel ter multiplos ui-view ("ng-view"). Da uma lida na documentacao.